# how can i use an chrome extension in my selenium python program?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

im just trying to use an vpn extension with selenium. I have the extension running , but i need to click in the button and enable the vpn so it can works, there's a way to do that with selenium? im thinking to use another similar option like scrapy or pyautogui...

Comment: The question is more general opinion. What is your exact question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** there is **no way** to **enable** the VPN on your extension

If you want to use your VPN extension you have to set a **profile** (otherwise selenium will create a **new profile** without installed extension)

Comment: i already have the extension with the browser that opened selenium. the issue  is that if i want to activate it , i have to enable it manually clicking the extension icon and enable... thanks

Comment: Yes thats not possible with selenium. I think you have to use (as you said) something like pyautogui :(